# Typescript - Create object based on another

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following object (this is the service response):

```
let contentArray = {
   "errorMessages":[
      
   ],
   "output":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "excecuteDate":"2022-02-04T13:34:20"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "excecuteDate":"2022-02-04T12:04:20"
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "excecuteDate":"2022-02-01T11:23:34"
      },
      {
         "id":4,
         "excecuteDate":"2022-01-14T10:30:54"
      },
      {
         "id":5,
         "excecuteDate":"2021-11-03T10:20:43"
      }
   ]
}
```

Based on the previous object I have to create the following:

```
{
   "2021":{
      "11-November":{
         "03/11/2021":[
            "10:20:43"
         ]
      }
   },
   "2022":{
      "01_January":{
         "14/01/2022":[
            "10:30:54"
         ]
      },
      "02_February":{
         "01/02/2022":[
            "11:23:34"
         ],
         "04/02/2022":[
            "12:04:20", "13:34:20"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

To be able to paint something like this on the screen:

[image]

I updated the question to be more specific. Based on the above, I have this code:

```
        let dateExecutionValue: Date;
        let i: number = 0;
        let tree = {};
        while (i < this.contentArray.length) {
            dateExecutionValue = new Date(this.contentArray[i].excecuteDate);
            let year = dateExecutionValue.getFullYear();
            tree[year] = {};
            let auxYear = year;
            while (auxYear === year && i < this.contentArray.length) {
                let month = dateExecutionValue.getMonth() + 1;
                // here, now under the year property of the object, I want to create another month property (for each month associated with that year)
                i++;
            }    
        }
```

How could I do it? thanks,

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post the relavent attempts in the question.

Comment: I'm working on it, as soon as I have it advanced I'll post it, thanks

Comment: Please do a minimal work on the requirement before posting the question rather than asking complete solution here

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N549Bw) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I'll review your proposal, thanks, anyway please update the question to be more precise.

Comment: Wow, I was trying to solve it with control breaks, but your solution is what I need and with less code, thanks a lot.

Comment: @jcalz, great usage of the logical assignment operators `||=` and `??=` !

Answer (score 0):

1. Iterate through the response
2. Apply some logic to transform returned value into a date and push into new property
3. Insert into html / DOM Manipulation